Raspberry PI4B Loadcell HX711 issues with reading data
I connected loadcell to hx711 amplifier and that to my RPi. When I try to run the code I get a few "False" outputs and after that I get an error "stdev requires at least two data points". I followed a tutorial on youtube by "Brian J - Engineering Videos" and there are no issues but I keep getting this error. Even that "False" is wrong, I should get some numbers and not "False".
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from hx711 import HX711
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
hx =HX711(dout_pin=6, pd_sck_pin=5)
while True:
    reading = hx.get_raw_data_mean()
    print (reading)

I checked all connections multiple times and went through code in "HX711" and "statistics" libraries to the best of my understanding and couldn't find an issue. I looked on the internet as much as I could and asked ChatGPT for help but nothing works.
